# Salesforce: bell notifications are not sent to the approver

Tags: notifications, salesforce

I am new to salesforce. I am not able to figure out how the bell notifications are disable in my code.

There is an approval process in the application, which has accept, reject and send for edits. The examples I see are showing the notifications are sent to approver but in my application the approver is not receiving bell notification. When the user is sending a submit for approval it is showing approval requests.

I see there is apex code which send custom notification.

How can we enable or disable bell notification for a particular record type?

I have see options for email notifications but not for bell notification.

Comment: You'll have to post some of that code. Or search in it for stuff related to "CustomNotification" and see if you can wrap something in an if statement...

Comment: Thank you for your response, so if there is a CustomNotification defined then the default notification is not sent?